# Как писать «веб-сайт» или «сайт»?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

В существующем переводе на Transifex во многих местах встречается «веб-сайт», как перевод термина "website". Это, на мой взгляд, слишком официально. Может быть, повсеместно перейдём на простое и гуманное «сайт»?

Comment: веб-сайт, веб-страница, Интернет (с большой буквы), всемирная паутина — мне все эти слова напоминают о глухих девяностых, когда компьютеры были диковинкой, а интернет — легендой.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а имена собственные пишутся с большой буквы

Comment: @mymedia да, но есть исключения. Например, «светит солнце» или «взошла луна» — с маленькой, а если мы сравниваем расстояния от Земли до Солнца и до Луны — с большой. Интернет в последнее время пишут с маленькой, потому что он стал чем-то повседневным и общедоступным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

Использовать термин «сайт».

---

*Остальные варианты*.

- «ресурс».
- «веб-сайт».